# Python terminated does not return to command line

Tags: python, multithreading

UPDATE: I found the bug. The serial port openned in listner should be closed when stopping thread. I was not doing that.

I have a simple python program where in its main, it starts 2 threads by calling their `start()` function. When the user presses a specific key, the program goes and clears the condition,`self.is_running=false`, that those 2 threads check everytime, so they would terminate when it's false:

```
def run(self):
    ...
    while self.is_running:
       ...
    return
```

Problem is I see threads terminate, but the program never returns to command prompt, and there is no combination of keys, `ctrl+x` etc. that would make it return to command prompt. I have to manually close the console window and restart a new one if I want to use the terminal console. I even used `sys.exit()` after threads are terminated but still doesn't make a difference.[image]

Do you know where am I going wrong?

Here is the minimal code:

main.py:

```
def main():

    listner_thread = None
    try:
        listner_thread = listner.listner()
        listner_thread.start();        
    except:
        Message = "Listener Thread Failed To Start"
        print (Message)
        return


    ui_thread=None
    try:
        ui_thread = ui.ui(listner_thread)
        ui_thread.start();          
    except:
        Message = "UI Thread Failed To Start"
        print (Message)
        return

    return  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

listener.py and ui.py threads:

```
class listner(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.port=serial.serial('COM11',115200)  

    def run(self):
        ...
        while self.is_running:
            self.port.read(1) 
        return
```

Where threads are instructed to be terminated are in ui thread:

ui.py

```
class ui(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,listner):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)     
        self.listner=listner

    def run(self):
        Message = ('\n    Starting Thread (' +  self.name + ')\n')
        print Message

        self.running = True


        while self.running:
            user = raw_input('\n   Q- Quit\n')

            if user.isalpha() and user.upper() == 'Q':
                self.listner.is_running= False
                self.running = False

        return
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ control flow is breaking from the `while` loops? The would seem like the likeliest culprit to me.

Comment: You probably want to write up a [MCVE] that demonstrates the behaviour you're describing. It's a little unlikely anyone can help you with it from a snippet of pseudocode and a screenshot.

Comment: 'minimal' is not quite enough, 'complete' and 'verifiable' also count. Nobody can reproduce your issue from what you've provided which is the point of the [MCVE]

Comment: We cannot discern from your example what's going wrong with your process flow, but I'd bet on the `self.is_running` status variable. Are you using `threading.Event` for it, or are you just winging it with generics? Because in the latter case you might have some race condition that prevents setting your flag... Also, explain how your main thread communicates to the child threads that they should stop running? As a last resort use `os._exit()` if you want to force killing of your threads, but you should be able to control your process flow and not rely on such 'hacks'...

Comment: I don't use event. Simply ui thread checks the user input, if it's 'Q', then it makes self_running= False.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use it. In your main thread create `kill_switch = threading.Event()`, pass that to your threads as you create them and have them loop with `while not passed_kill_switch.is_set()` Also, after thread initialization create the same loop for your main thread so you can control everything centrally. Then all you're left to do is call `passed_kill_switch.set()` when you want your threads to exit their loops and you're done.

Comment: This code is still incomplete and is sort of pseudocode. It doesn't run, bits are missing, etc. Please, for the nth time, read up on what a [MCVE] is. Then write one. Often, that can be enough for you to find your problem. But there is zero chance of anyone finding a problem in your code looking at some other code that doesn't even run and you yourself have not even tried.

Comment: @pvg you're right. Code is not as it should and it doesn't show where the fault might be. Because it's distributed between a PC host and a microprocessor board I can't include it effectively because then I have to include microprocessor code too.

Comment: @dandikain - you don't have to include microprocessor code - you can strip down your listener.py for starters so it only includes the thread management code. It's probably the thread that never exits...

Comment: @zwer - In listener I had a serial port open. It was not being closed (`port.close()`) upon thread terminatinon with setting 'is_running=False' , when I added `port.close()` it exited the thread properly.

Answer (score 1):

You set `running` to `False` on the UI thread instance, but never mutate `running` on the listener thread instance. Your listener thread will thus never exit.

Try lifting the exit condition to a global, like `should_exit = False`. The UI thread can then set this `True`, and, since the global scope is shared across threads, both should see the change.

Comment: In UI thread, I have `self.listner.is_running= False` which is listener thread running condition.

Comment: But you never assign `listner` on the UI thread, so that seems unlikely to do much.

Comment: You are right. I didn't include that here for brevity. But in real code it's there.

Comment: As a general rule, you need real code to get real answers.

Answer (score 0):

In listener I had a serial port open. It was not being closed (`port.close()`) upon thread terminatinon with setting 'is_running=False' , when I added `port.close()` it exited the thread properly.